# Installing ExifRead module into QGIS 2.14

Tags: qgis-2.10, qgis-2.14, exifread

I'm attempting to install ExifRead into QGIS. Assuming zero knowledge of python coding. Is there a command code I can send which will install the .whl? I'm having zero luck following python's own guide.

Answer (score 1):

A less technical approach to install ExifRead (also works for standalone QGIS) is as follows:

1. Download the python library from https://github.com/ianare/exif-py/releases. Select the Zip file format.
2. Extract the folder `"ExifRead-2.1.2"` (the version number may vary) to any location on your hard drive. Although `"C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages"` should be preferred.
3. In the folder `"C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages"` (or any other folder that is configured within the QGIS python-path environement) add a new file `"exiftools.pth"` with just one line of text containing the path to the folder where you extracted the files at step 1 into. In my case that file would contain the following line:
          `C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages\ExifRead-2.1.2`
4. Restart QGIS for an update of the pythonpath environment.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through this again after updating QGIS to 2.14.2 on my windows 7 machine which stopped PhototoShape working.

Install PIP to extract the .whl

I installed PIP from the OSGEO4W command prompt
for instructions see https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki/ExternalPythonPackages

> > > curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
> > >
> > > python get-pip.py

Then download the Exifread whl and paste it into 
Program Files\QGIS Essen\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages

change the command prompt to the site packages directory and then type pip install ExifRead-2.1.2-py2-none-any.whl (or whatever version you have).

And hopefully your sorted, this is my limit of knowledge on this so maybe somebody can explain it better...

Answer (score 0):

I just opened, OSGEO4W as administrator and filed in:python –m pip install exifread. That's it!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install the Exifread library using  Osgeo4W [image]